# breaking dates out by the first day of each quarter

Tags: javascript

I have a method right now that takes a date in string format like `YYYY-MM` and breaks it out to a quarter format like `Q1 2016`.

```
var mth_dt = new Date(d.mth_dt).getMonth() + 1;
var quarter = Math.ceil(mth_dt / 3)
var yrq = d.mth_dt.substr(0,4).toString();
var qtrYr = "Q"+quarter+" "+yrq

//console.log("qtrYr: ", qtrYr);

return qtrYr;
```

what I was wondering now, is how do I get it to result in the 1st date of each quarter? For instance, `Q1 2016` would be `1/1/2016` and `Q2 2016` would be `4/1/2016`.

Comment: could you provide some sample input/output or an explanation of what it is currently doing wrong?  If nothing is currently wrong and you're just not sure of where to go could we get an idea of things you've already tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the month and day for a quarter are the same each year, why not do something like this:

```js
GetQuarter = function(month,year){
var quarter = "";

if (month/3 <= 1) 
 quarter = "Q1 01/01/"; 
else if(month/3 <= 2) 
 quarter ="Q2 04/01/"; 
else if(month/3 <= 3) 
 quarter ="Q3 07/01/";
else 
 quarter = "Q4 10/01/";

return quarter += year;
}

document.write(GetQuarter(11,2016)) // Q4 10/01/2016
```